# laravel sort an array by date

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting

hello friends I have an array that looks like this:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "date" => "2016-05-31 15:08:33"
    0 => "31 May 16"
    1 => "aze"
    2 => "2"
    3 => "hi"
    4 => "487841464704194.jpg"
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "date" => "2016-05-31 15:26:09"
    0 => "31 May 16"
    1 => "aze"
    2 => "2"
    3 => "hey"
    4 => "487841464704194.jpg"
  ]
  2 => array:6 [▼
    "date" => "2016-06-01 11:33:06"
    0 => "01 Jun 16"
    1 => "aze"
    2 => "2"
    3 => "Dm me please"
    4 => "487841464704194.jpg"
  ]
]
```

My goal is to sort it by the `date`. So from new to old.

If tried this:

```
$comarrSorted = $comarr->sortByDesc('date');
dd($comarrSorted);
```

But I get this nasty error:

```
Call to a member function sortByDesc() on array
```

Anyone can help me out? I guess the error is caused because it's a collection function? Is it not possible to sort my array with this function?

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: use usort function

Comment: refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create your own function

```
array_sort_by_column($array, 'date');


function array_sort_by_column(&$array, $column, $direction = SORT_ASC) {
    $reference_array = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $row) {
        $reference_array[$key] = $row[$column];
    }

    array_multisort($reference_array, $direction, $array);
}
```

Comment: There must be an easier way to do this with Laravel, or am I mistaken?

Comment: This is easier way, & I think, laravel not provide any array related function. If you get any better answer please let me know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52368760/10888237 This answer below is the better solution.

Answer (score 22):

You can convert to a `collection`, call the `sortBy()` and the convert back to an `array` all on one line.

```
$sortedArr = collect($array)->sortBy('date')->all();
```

Comment: This gives back a collection, for converting it back to an array, we can use the `values()` function. `$sortedArr = collect($array)->sortBy('date')->values();`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `usort()` with custom comarison function.

```
function sortByDate($arr1, $arr2)
{
    $tmp1 = strtotime($arr1['date']);
    $tmp2 = strtotime($arr2['date']);
    return $tmp1 - $tmp2;
}
usort($array, 'date');
```

Comment: But I only have 1 array what do I ned $arr1 and $arr2 for?

Comment: I've added new answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this solution to get the result:

```
collect($yourArray)->sortBy('Key')->values();
```