# Sorting arrays in Laravel following a specific parametre

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have a variable which is an array of arrays

```
$janvier[]=array( 'type', 'date');
```

I want to sort it following the date so I used this code

```
$janvier=> $janvier->sortby($janvier['date'])
```

but it shows me this error:

> call to a member function sortby() on array

Couldn't find what's wrong

I'm so used to low level languages this is my first time using a high level language

Answer (score 1):

`sortBy` is a collection method from laravel, you can't use it on a array.

If you want to sort the array by the key `data` use this code:

```
$janvier = array_multisort(array_values($janvier), SORT_DESC, array_keys($janvier), SORT_ASC, $janvier);
```

Look at the [array_multisort](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) method for more info

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help but this just made the content of the array to NULL

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom function for this case:

```
array_sort_by_column($array, 'date');

function array_sort_by_column(&$array, $column, $direction = SORT_ASC) {
    $reference_array = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $row) {
        $reference_array[$key] = $row[$column];
    }

    array_multisort($reference_array, $direction, $array);
}
```

For more you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567751/laravel-sort-an-array-by-date)