# Order a array by date in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5

I want to order an array with customer comments by the field **date**. From the most current date to the oldest.

```
$testimonials = array:356 [▼
0 => array:4 [▼
    "comment" => "blahblahblahblahblah"
    "name" => "John"
    "date" => "12/04/2019"
]
1 => array:4 [▼
  "comment" => "blah blah blah blah blah"
  "name" => "Franky V"
  "date" => "13/05/2019"
]
2 => array:4 [▼
  "comment" => "lololololol"
  "name" => "Peter"
  "date" => "06/03/2020"
]
3 => array:4 [▼
  "comment" => "blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah"
  "name" => "Hugo"
  "date" => "24/01/2019"
]
....
```

I want to get this result:

```
$testimonials = array:356 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "comment" => "lololololol"
    "name" => "Peter"
    "date" => "06/03/2020"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "comment" => "blah blah blah blah blah"
    "name" => "Franky V"
    "date" => "13/05/2019"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "comment" => "blahblahblahblahblah"
    "name" => "John"
    "date" => "12/04/2019"
  ]
  3 => array:4 [▼
    "comment" => "blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah"
    "name" => "Hugo"
    "date" => "24/01/2019"
  ]
```

How can I do this within my Laravel controller or with PHP?

EDIT: I'm trying with usort but I get it wrong

```
public function getTrollingDates($testimonials) {
        $currentdate = new DateTime();
        $currentdate = $currentdate->format('Y-m-d');

        foreach($testimonials as &$testimonial) {
            $testimonial['date'] = $this->getRandomDate('2019-01-01',$currentdate);
        }

        $testimonials = usort($testimonials, 'compare');



        return $testimonials;
    }


    public function compare($a, $b)    {
        return  strtotime($b['date']) - strtotime($a['date']) ;
    }
```

This return me this error:

```
usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'compare' not found or invalid function name
```

Comment: I think this link would be the answer to you.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567751/laravel-sort-an-array-by-date/52368760](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567751/laravel-sort-an-array-by-date/52368760)

Comment: I think this article would be help to you.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567751/laravel-sort-an-array-by-date/52368760](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567751/laravel-sort-an-array-by-date/52368760)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$testimonials` is a collection object, you can make use of [`sortByDesc()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortbydesc) to sort by dates in decreasing order.

```
<?php 

$testimonials = $testimonials->sortByDesc(function($a){
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$a['date']);
});

dd($testimonials);
```

Comment: @AntonioMorales What kind of new date? It works fine on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

In `Laravel` you can do it like:

```
$array = collect($testimonials)->sortBy('date')->reverse()->toArray();
```

And in `PHP` you can use `usort` to achieve the same

```
function compare($a, $b)    {

   // if you want to sort by ascending
    return  strtotime($b['date']) - strtotime($a['date']) ;

    //if you want to sort by descending order
    // return  strtotime($a['date'])  - strtotime($b['date'])  ;
}
usort($my_array, 'compare');
```

[PHP -> usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: @AntonioMorales Change  `usort($testimonials, 'compare');` to   `usort($testimonials, $this->compare);`

Comment: Now throw out this new bug: Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\WebController::$compare

Comment: @AntonioMorales Instead of `function` try `anonymous function`  : `usort($testimonials,  function($a, $b){
 return  strtotime($b['date']) - strtotime($a['date']) ;
});`

Comment: Not working : usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, no array or string given

Comment: try this: `$array = collect($testimonials)->sortBy('date')->reverse()->toArray();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210054/discussion-between-sehdev-and-antonio-morales).